# How to add object to a nested array in mongoDB and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have no clue how can I push an object to a nested array

this is the Board document:

```
{
    "boardMembers": [
        "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d"
    ],
    "boardLists": [
        {
            "cards": [],
            "_id": "5f6387e077beba2e3c15d15a",
            "title": "list one",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5f63877177beba2e3c15d159",
    "boardName": "board1",
    "boardPassword": "123456",
    "boardCreator": "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d",
    "g_createdAt": "2020-09-17T15:57:37.616Z",
    "__v": 2
}
```

I need to push a task inside the cards array (to a specific list with ID)

here is the code:

```
outer.post("/add-task/:id", auth, boardAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const listId = req.params.id;

 
    const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: req.board._id });
    if (!board) return res.status(404).send("no such board");

    const list = await List.findOne({ _id: listId });
    if (!list) return res.status(404).send("List not found");

    const task = new Task({
      text: req.body.text,
    });

    board.boardLists.map((list) => {
      if (listId.toString() === list._id.toString()) {
        list.cards.push(task);
      } else {
        console.log("no task");
      }
    });

    await board.save();
    res.send(board);
});
```

now the problem is when I make the request in postman its shows me the task inside the cards array i want but its not saving it to the mongoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `array.map()` but:

1. Nothing is returned in the callback of `map()`, which will return an array with each element `undefined`;
2. You aren't assigning the array returned by `map()` to anything.

So, you can use `array.map()` to return an array in which the `task` is pushed to the desired list in `board.boardLists` like so:

```js
board.boardLists = board.boardLists.map((list) => {
  if (listId.toString() === list._id.toString()) {
    return {
      ...list,
      cards: list.cards.concat(task)
    }
  } else {
    return list
  }
});
```

Comment: just add a  " , " after `...list` and try